# The input is not a valid Base-64 string when decoding valid base64 string

Tags: c#, stream, base64, decode

The below code throws a FormatException, although the input string is a valid base64 string.

Why?

`System.FormatException The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.`

```
string expectedString = "this";
byte[] expectedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(expectedString);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(expectedBytes);
var input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(base64String));
using FromBase64Transform myTransform = new FromBase64Transform();
using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(input, myTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

using var sr = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
string str = await sr.ReadToEndAsync(); // Throws 
    
Assert.Equal(expectedString, str);
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In wich line?

Comment: Maybe try using `UTF8` instead of `Unicode` for the encoding.

Comment: The error is when calling ReadToEndAsync() (comment "Throws")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Martin, replacing with UTF8 works.

So FromBase64Transform or CryptoStream may only support UTF8

Working code:

```
string expectedString = "this is a test";
byte[] expectedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(expectedString);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(expectedBytes);
var input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64String));
using FromBase64Transform myTransform = new FromBase64Transform();
using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(input, myTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

using var sr = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
string str = await sr.ReadToEndAsync(); // OK

// Note: str != expectedString 'literally' because base64String is UTF-16 and we've used Encoding.UTF8 to get the bytes from it.
```

Thanks!

Comment: You call StreamReader without an encoding and the default is utf8. Base64 does not know anything about the bytes its encodes. IT takes the bytes transform its into an "ASCII" safe form and back. BUt that are just bytes in bytes out.

Comment: If you look at the source code for the `FromBase64Transform` class, it operates on UTF-8: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6a889d234267a4c96ed21d0e1660dce787d78a38/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Base64Transforms.cs#L304